# Overloading (not specializing) templates in std namespace

Tags: c++, c++11, std, language-lawyer

This is very pedantic but in C++03 it was apparently non-conforming for a program to **overload** (not **specialize**) a template function in the `std` namespace: see mention of this [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-throwing_swap#cite_note-0) and [long discussion on comp.lang.c++.moderated](http://groups.google.ca/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/browse_thread/thread/b396fedad7dcdc81)

i.e. this was ok:

```
namespace std
{
    template <>
    void swap (Foo & f, Foo & g)
    {
       // ...
    }
}
```

but this was not (if I understand correctly...):

```
namespace std
{
    template <typename T>
    void swap (TempateFoo<T> & f, TempateFoo<T> & g)
    {
       // ...
    }
}
```

Is this still true in C++11? Also, does this apply to template classes (like `std::hash`) too, or just template functions?

EDIT: also, is there any example of a standard library implementation such that the latter would break things in practice? And if not, is there a specific reason for disallowing overloads like in the second case above? (what could potentially break in theory?)

Comment: I think you cannot open `std` namespace for things other than specialization of templates.

Comment: So the second example is still illegal?

Comment: Yes, but I'm **not** 100% sure.

Comment: ok...i tagged this language-lawyer for a reason :)

Comment: Remember that the answer to the question *"is there any example of standard library implementation such that the latter would break things in practice?"* might be NONE, but that doesn't mean that it will not break in future (if the Standard doesn't allow *such* addition to `std` namespace).

Comment: of course :) just curious, though

Comment: *"does this apply to template classes too"* - How would you overload a class in the first place?

Comment: @ChristianRau yeah, I realize now it's different

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible to define a partial specialization of a function template in C++, so your second example defines an overload *not* a specialization.  Since the standard only allows specializations to be added to namespace `std`, your overload is illegal.

> Is this still true in C++11?

Yes.

> Also, does this apply to template classes (like std::hash) too, or just template functions?

You can't overload class templates anyway, you can only overload functions.  The same rules apply though, you can only specialize a class template if the specialization depends on a user-defined (meaning non-standard) type.

> is there a specific reason for disallowing overloads like in the second case above? (what could potentially break in theory?)

As one example, the implementation might want to take the address of a function but if you've overloaded the function then taking the address could cause an ambiguity and fail to compile, meaning you've just broken valid code in the standard library.

Comment: OK, great, that last part makes sense.

Comment: is partial specialization (of, eg. std::hash) with user-defined types ok, or just full specialization?

Comment: if the partial specialization depends on a user-defined type it's ok, e.g. `std::hash<MyTemplate<T>>` is OK because it depends on `MyTemplate<T>` which is a user-defined type

Comment: Cool, is that last part (partial specializations in `std` on user-defined types being OK) new or was that true in C++03 as well?

Comment: "meaning non-standard" -- [I wish it was that clear](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23659222/1774667)

Comment: @Yakk, it isn't properly specified (and that's a defect) but when the library clauses (17-30) say "user-defined" they mean non-standard, so `std::string` is not a user-defined type. When the language clauses say "user-defined" they mean not fundamental, so `std::string` _is_ user-defined. But in the context of this question it means a type not defined in the standard.

Answer (score 6):

n3376 17.6.4.2.1

> The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace std or to a
> namespace within namespace std unless otherwise specified. A program may add a template specialization
> for any standard library template to namespace std only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type
> and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly
> prohibited.

17.6.4.2.2

> The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it declares
>
> — an explicit specialization of any member function of a standard library class template, or
>
> — an explicit specialization of any member function template of a standard library class or class template,
> or
>
> — an explicit or partial specialization of any member class template of a standard library class or class
> template.
>
> A program may explicitly instantiate a template defined in the standard library only if the declaration
> depends on the name of a user-defined type and the instantiation meets the standard library requirements
> for the original template.

Comment: great, thanks! any clue why overloads aren't allowed, though? it's apparently come up in discussion enough so I have to imagine there's a reason for the restriction.

Comment: I'm accepting this for now but if anyone can follow up with reasoning behind this restriction that would be great :) (I'm sure someone must have brought this up with the committee.)

Comment: Adding an overload can cause existing *unrelated* calls to use that overload instead of whatever they were using before. Unrelated as in not mentioning your user-defined type at all. Specializations can't do that.