# How is C++ function template implemented in assembly?

Tags: c++, assembly

I am trying to implement C++ function using assembly code -- ARMv7-a, to be specific. 
Now I encounter a program that I don't know how C++ function template should be 
implemented in assembly. I try to compile the source code with -S -O1 flag to see the 
generated assembly but couldn't understand it. Can any one give me a brief idea how the 
C++ template is **translated into assembly code**? Just use the following simple function
as an example:

```
template<typename T>
T f(T a) {
   return a + 1;
}
```

If you found any other function is easier to do the explain, please do so. Thanks!

Comment: You wanna return a T, not void.

Comment: Use your compiler to compile a simple example with a few different types for the templates parameters and look at the assembly it produces. That should give you a good idea of what the assembly should look like. If you don't understand what the output is, your question should be able getting help with that.

Comment: @mah a useful thing is to embed comments, eg `asm("#begin template")` which will show up in `.s` file

Comment: Modern compilers are excellent at generating optimized assembly code.   I'm not questioning your personal expertise, but trying to out-optimize the compiler seems like a very difficult task with a small payoff.

Comment: @DanKorn he might just want to play around, which is a more-than legitimate reason to do this.

Comment: I'm really amazed at the speed that people respond here. Thank you guys so much and sorry for the mistake in the code. The reason why I ask this is because I will use the NEON instructions for ARM to speed up the program, which operates on vectors of registers instead of just plain register. And the function want to implement is written in function template (thanks Nikos), that's why I ask the question. I think implementing each instance of the template separately is what I will do here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It would help, to phrase it correctly. It's not template function, it's **function template** ... noticed the difference?

A template, is to generate code upon instantiation. So in this case, if you instantiate your `f` for `int` the assembly would be identical with

```
int f(int a) { // Note that having a return type void is wrong here
   return a + 1;
}
```

There's lack of binary code generation for non instantiated templates. That's why lots of errors in template code remain dormant until instantiation for the problematic types is performed.

So for a real example, here are the 2 versions, one generated out of a function template and one out of a function (both for `int`); if it wasn't for the hint at the right one couldn't tell the differene:

```
    f2(1);
00BA25BE  push        1  
00BA25C0  call        f2<int> (0BA12F3h)  
00BA25C5  add         esp,4  
    f(1);
00BA25C8  push        1  
00BA25CA  call        f (0BA12EEh)  
00BA25CF  add         esp,4
```

More on templates (types this time) and binary code representation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23660294/2567683)

Comment: Implementations are required to check function templates for e.g. syntax errors, even if they are not instantiated.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, ok basic syntax checking; I stressed the dormant errors to display the lack of code generation for non instantiated types. Would you propose any rephrasing or should I complement with the existence of syntax checking?

Comment: It is more than basic syntax checking. Non-dependent names are also looked up. It may be better to remove that line entirely, because it is complicated!

Answer (score 6):

You should implement each *instance* of the template in separate assembly.

Fundamentally, each template instance is a different type. You'll also need to deal with specialisations; partial or otherwise.

(Of course that means that you need to know in advance which set of `T`s you need, but that is essentially what a C++ compiler does.)

Comment: It should be noted that the template types are filled in at compile time, and thus the assembly code that is emitted depends wholly on the type it was generated for.