# Overload of operator<< not found when called from std::ostream_iterator?

Tags: c++, c++11

This program

```
// main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>

template<typename t1, typename t2>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::pair<t1, t2>& pair)
{
  return os << "< " << pair.first << " , " << pair.second << " >";
}

int main() 
{
  std::map<int, int> map = { { 1, 2 }, { 2, 3 } };
  std::cout << *map.begin() << std::endl;//This works

  std::copy(
    map.begin(),
    map.end(),
    std::ostream_iterator<std::pair<int,int> >(std::cout, " ")
  ); //this doesn't work
}
```

produces an error

> `no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream_iterator<std::pair<int, int> >::ostream_type {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘const std::pair<int, int>’)`

I guess this isn't working because my overload isn't available inside `std::copy`, but why is that?

Comment: I have no idea why people are down-voting this question, it's intention is clear, although the title could be written in a better matter.

Comment: @ Filip Roséen - refp Simply there are many idiots in the forum that like to down-vote. The problem is that in the second case an appropriate operator-function is searched in namespace std:: when instantiates template class std::ostream_iterator.. As there are already declared operator << in namespace std  then the search is stopped. The compiler does not find the operator defined in the global namespace.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow that is **not** the answer; I'm working on a detailed description. I'll ping both you and chris when it's available.

Comment: @Filip Roséen - refp See the section of instantiating of templates and name searching.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I'll just have you read my answer when it's available.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Since when is Stack Overflow a "forum"?

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp thank you so much for the explanation I get it all, sorry if my answer was kind of dumb.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Explanation

Since `operator<<` is being called in an *unqualified* manner from inside *namespace std* (more specifically inside *std::ostream_iterator*), and all the arguments involved are also declared in the same namespace, **only** namespace `std` will be searched for potential matches.

---

#### Hackish solution

```
namespace std {
  template<typename t1, typename t2>
  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::pair<t1, t2>& pair)
  {
     return os << "< " << pair.first << " , " << pair.second << " >";
  }
}
```

<sup>**Note**: You can only specialize templates that includes *user-defined types* inside `namespace std`, the above snippet is therefore potentially ill-formed according to the Standard (if `std::pair<T1,T2>` isn't a user-declared type, see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23659222/1090079)).</sup>

---

#### Detailed explanation

Below we have *namespace N* which will aid us in trying to simulate your usage of *namespace std*, and what is going on when the compiler tries to find a suitable overload for a given type.

**namespace N**

```
namespace N {
  struct A { };
  struct B { };

  void func (A value) { std::cout << "A"; }

  template<class T>
  void call_func (T value) { func (value); }
}
```

---

**main.cpp**

```
void func (N::B value) {
  std::cout << "B";
}
```

```
int main() {
  N::A a;
  N::B b;

  func (a);         // (1)
  func (b);         // (2)

  N::call_func (a); // (3a)
  N::call_func (b); // (3b)
}
```

**Notes**:

1. Without knowing about *Argument-dependent lookup*, one might be surprised that the compiler is able to find the suitable overload required to make (*1*) work.

   ADL states that upon using an *unqualified-name* in a function call, not only is the current namespace searched for suitable overloads, the namespace of the arguments are also searched; and this is how the compiler finds `N::func`, even though we didn't write so explicitly.
2. We have a suitable overload in the current namespace; it's all good in the hood.
3. ...

   **Why does (3a) compile, whereas (3b) will result in a nasty diagnostic?**

   When we instantiate the template `N::call_func<T>` it will try to pass on the argument of type `T` to the *unqualified* function named `func`.

   Since the rules of *name-lookup* says that the current namespace, **and** the namespace of the arguments involved, are searched for suitable matches in case we are calling a function from a *unqualified* name, it will **only** search *namespace N* if `T` is a type declared in *namespace N*.

   Both `N::A` and `N::B` are declared in *namespace N*, so the compiler will **not** search any other scope to find a suitable overload; which is why lookup fails.

Comment: I concede defeat on there being no way to definitively answer (although I still fault the OP in not posting the actual error), but do note that both the OP's overload and the one in your answer where it is placed inside `std` are illegal.

Comment: @juanchopanza oh snap, fixed!

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp, Hmm, wouldn't that conflict with other uses of "user-declared"? For example, "If
there is no user-declared constructor for class X, a constructor having no parameters is implicitly declared
as defaulted (8.4)." Take something like `std::string`. With this definition, there is no user-declared constructor, but the implicitly added one would conflict. I'm open to the argument that I'm equivocating on user-declared then (or just messing up and it actually only being user-defined). Anyway, the wording looks fine and I'd better go look at the question that actually debates this.

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp, I will, thanks. `[std-proposals]` is where I usually end up going.

Comment: @chris we should remove our comments since they are now obsolete, and/or not related to the current post. Come hang out in the *C++* chat; [Lounge<C++>](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec)!

Comment: The restriction on overloaded operators has nothing to do with "user-declared".  The requirement is "at least one argument whose type is a class, a reference to a class, an enumeration, or a reference to an enumeration".  You may have been thinking of specializations of `std` templates, but that `operator<<` is an overload, and not a specialization of any other primary template.

Answer (score 2):

Although the question has already been answered I just want to add that there is a better way to print a map without abusing the copy function for this.
There is also a transform function which is more suitable for doing something like this.
I rewrote your example to give you a hint how you could use the transform function to convert the map into strings and print them to the std::cout:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<algorithm>
#include<sstream>

template<typename t1, typename t2>
 std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::pair<t1, t2>& pair)
 {
     return os << "< " << pair.first << " , " << pair.second << " >";
 }

std::string toString(const std::pair<int, int>& pair) {
    std::ostringstream str;
    str << "<" << pair.first << ", " << pair.second << ">";
    return str.str();
}

int main()
 {
  std::map<int, int> map = { std::make_pair(1, 2), std::make_pair(2, 3)};
  std::cout << *map.begin() << std::endl;//This works
  std::transform(map.begin(), map.end(),
  std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"), toString);
}
```