# Why is std::modulus defined such that it only works for integer-numbers and not for floating point

Tags: c++, c++11, std

From [C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/modulus/) I take that std::modulus is defined such that it behaves like (for C++11)

```
template <class T> struct modulus {
   T operator() (const T& x, const T& y) const {return x%y;}
   typedef T first_argument_type;
   typedef T second_argument_type;
   typedef T result_type;
};
```

This means, that due to the use of `%` it can only be used for integer numbers. Is there a reason why it is not implemented such, that it could be used for floating point numbers as well?

Maybe I am missing the point, so all hints are very appreciated.

**EDIT to reply to comment:** So to give an example of what I would whish for with floating point numbers which is derived from the example from C++ Reference:

```
// modulus example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <functional>   // std::modulus, std::bind2nd
#include <algorithm>    // std::transform

int main () {
    float numbers[]={1.,2.,3.,4.,5.};
    float remainders[5];
    std::transform (numbers, numbers+5, remainders,    std::bind2nd(std::modulus<double>(),2.5));
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
        std::cout << numbers[i] << " is " <<    (remainders[i]==0?"even":"odd") << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

But obviously this causes a compiler error like:

```
error C2296: '%' : illegal, left operand has type 'const double'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xfunctional(69) : while compiling class template member function 'double std::modulus<_Ty>::operator ()(const _Ty &,const _Ty &) const'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=double
1>          ]
1>          main.cpp(16) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::modulus<_Ty>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=double
1>          ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xfunctional(70): error C2297: '%' : illegal, right operand has type 'const double'
```

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Exactly the same way as for integers.

Comment: All these functors (plus, minus, etc.) are defined to use the built-in operators so that these can be passed as parameters (which you cannot do with `+` or `-` directly). It was not intended to add extra functionality.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Try it.

Comment: for instance if I want to wrap an angle to [-2pi,2pi] like mod(angle,2pi)

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Most `floats` will lose massive amounts of precision when cast to `int`, and a modulus operation on the result will therefore deliver the wrong answer. This is rather obvious.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Basic version: `double modulus(double a, double b) { return a - b * std::floor(a / b); }`

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius So `fmod()` doesn't exist?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I've addressed that. Because of the increased range. Your objections seem extremely obtuse.

Comment: This is nonsense mathematically speaking. what is the modulo of (1/Pi)? EDIT: i meant 1%PI

Comment: @GuillaumePaniagua http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod

Comment: @Guillaume Paniagua I do not argue it is mathematically strange. However, in programming there exist constructs like fmod. Your question of what modulus of (1/Pi) is makes no sense, as this is merely a division. Or do you mean mod(1,pi)?

Comment: Yeah but they called it fmod not mod for that reason this is not a modulus. "%" is the mathematical equivalent of euclidean division rest calculus and only this. We can't reinvent mathematics this is the answer and reason why modulus does not perform this kind of operation. If the question is how can we perform the operation then fair enough.

Comment: @GuillaumePaniagua That's pretty confused. `%` is certainly a remainder operator, and `fmod()` is certainly a modulus function, but `fmod()` versus `mod()` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Programming languages often do not do the same thing as you would expect from a mathematically point of view. a = a + b is perfectly good in C++, even for non-zero b. However, in mathematics this is not really the case. A vector in C++ is not a mathematical vector. I am pretty sure this could go on a while. So I do not really see, why modulus in C++ cannot support something for floating point numbers which behaves like fmod.

Answer (score 4):

The various function objects in `<functional>` are intended to provide function objects for the various built-in operators. They are not intended as customization points or to extend beyond what the language defines. They also remained pretty much unchanged since they were proposed (in 1995 I think).

If you need different functionality, just create a suitable function object. With the current definition of C++ many of these function objects are mostly obsolete (they remain useful when the type of the function object needs to be spelled out). For example, this code is probably be more readable anyway

```
std::transform(numbers, numbers + 5, remainders,
    [](auto value){ return fmod(value, 2.5); });
```

... or even

```
std::transform(std::begin(numbers), std::end(numbers), std::begin(remainders),
   [](auto value){ return fmod(value, 2.5); });
```

Comment: This will not work since % is not working for floating point numbers, or am I wrong?

Comment: @Pi: sure - I was concentrating on getting the other stuff right: replaced `value % 2.5` by `fmod(value, 2.5)`...

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own version of the function that also handles floating point numbers:

```
template<class T, class = typename std::is_floating_point<T>::type>
struct MyModulus : std::modulus<T>
{};

template<class T>
struct MyModulus<T, std::true_type> : std::binary_function<T, T, T>
{
    T operator()(T a, T b) const { return std::fmod(a, b); }
};
```

---

Since you use C++11, prefer using lambdas to `std::bind`. Lambdas are more efficient and easier to write and read:

```
std::transform(numbers, numbers+5, remainders, [](double a) { 
    return std::fmod(a, 2.5); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Why it doesn't work**

According to [cplusplus.com `modulus` page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/modulus/):

> Binary function object class whose call returns the result of the modulus operation between its two arguments (as returned by operator %)

Since this is a wrapper to the legacy operator, which doesn't support floating point types, there is no such specialization.

**Possible solution (Not the suggested one)**

You could just add it yourself:

```
namespace std {
  template <>
  struct modulus<double> {
    double operator()(const double &lhs, const double &rhs) const {
      return fmod(lhs, rhs);
    }
  };
} // namespace std
```

And then it will work as intended:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << "fmod of 5.3 / 2.0 is " << fmod (5.3,2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "fmod of 5.3 / 2.0 is " << std::modulus<double>()(5.3, 2.0) << std::endl;
}
```

**Note:**

As comments pointed out, this type of overloading is not [highly recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15104760/overloading-not-specializing-templates-in-std-namespace) by the cpp standard, so be careful when using it:

> The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace std or to a namespace within namespace std unless otherwise specified. A program may add a template specialization for any standard library template to namespace std only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly prohibited.

Although our specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and even though it (probably) takes place in a private scope (*.cpp file), it still is considered undefined behavior (since we don't depend on a user-defined type).

**Better solution**

Instead, we could use this nifty trick to become 100% legitimate:

```
template < typename T, typename = typename std::is_floating_point<T>::type >
struct ModulusFP {
  ModulusFP(T val) : val(val) {}
  T val;

  operator T() const { return val; }
};

namespace std {
  template < typename T >
  struct modulus<ModulusFP<T>> : binary_function<T, T, T> {
    ModulusFP<T> operator()(const ModulusFP<T> &lhs, const ModulusFP<T> &rhs) const {
      return fmod(T(lhs), T(rhs));
    }
  };
} // namespace std
```

And then the code still works as intended, both for trivial uses and for more complicated ones:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << "fmod of 5.3 / 2.0 is " << fmod (5.3,2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "fmod of 5.3 / 2.0 is " << std::modulus<ModulusFP<double>>()(5.3, 2.0) << std::endl;

    float numbers[]={1.,2.,3.,4.,5.};
    float remainders[5];
    std::transform (numbers, numbers+5, remainders, std::bind2nd(std::modulus<ModulusFP<float>>(), 2.5));
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
        std::cout << numbers[i] << " is " <<    (remainders[i]==0?"even":"odd") << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you specialize an `std` template for a built-in type and in a different namespace?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin What 'different namespace'?

Comment: @EJP, I guess he means, not from inside the `std` namespace

Comment: `[namespace.std]` _The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace std or to a namespace within namespace std unless otherwise specified. A program may add a template specialization for any standard library template to namespace std only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly prohibited._

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Very good, but there is nothing there about 'from a different namespace'. `std::modulus` belongs to the `std::` namespace, and can only be overridden, if at all, from that namespace. Your original comment, or question, didn't make sense.

Comment: -1. According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std: "It is allowed to add template specializations for any standard library template to the namespace std only if the declaration depends on a ***user-defined type***". Specializing with `double` is undefined behavior.

Comment: @EJP To define a template specialization the code must open namespace `std` first. It does not.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I agree, but there is nothing in this answer that precludes that, or that justifies your original comment/question.

Comment: @EJP I agree to disagree agreeably.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Sure, but I'm still waiting for a answer to 'what different namespace?'

Comment: @lisyarus, I added a comment regarding just that and an implementation that is 100% legitimate

Comment: @DanielTrugman Nice! Still a -1 since all this does not answer the actual question (as an example, Dietmar Kühl's answer *does* provide an answer, in the very first sentence).

Comment: Also note that your functional object does not define the required typedefs, so that it does not compile with `std::bind`. A rather poor quality answer.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin, before you start trashing my answer, please make sure you know what you are talking about. It works perfectly with `std::bind`. Prepared an [example](https://repl.it/MTNj/latest) for you.

Comment: So many things wrong with this answer, yet you are asking me to know what I am talking about, lol. https://ideone.com/B2ljwg :

`error: specialization of ‘template<class _Tp> struct std::modulus’ in different namespace`, 
`error: no type named ‘first_argument_type’ in ‘struct std::modulus<double>`

Comment: This is undefined, period. Nothing gray about it.

Comment: @T.C., Updated answer and avoided this phrase.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin, you were right, newer GCC versions do complain about both the specialization in a different namespace (Wrapped specialization using `namespace std { .. }` instead of using `std::`) and about the `std::bind` (Improved by inheriting from `std::binary_function` to resolve that).