# No hash function in C++ STL (std::unordered_set) for std::list?

Tags: c++, c++11, hash, stl

I am trying to create a `unordered_set` of `list` of `string`.

But I am stuck with this error:

`/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1103:22: error: no match for call to ‘(const std::hash<std::list<std::basic_string<char> > >) (const std::list<std::basic_string<char> >&)’`

I suspect, this is because STL doesn't have a hash function for `list` of `string`.

Creating a `set` of the same type works, but I am worried about efficiency issues (insertion and look up times).

Is there any workaround for this? I don't want to implement a hash function for lists! But may be someone can suggest me some alternative ideas.

Comment: There is no hash function defined, as you say. So you don't want to fix the problem by defining a hash function, and you don't want to use a container that doesn't require one. Well, um, you just ruled out both your options for no reason :)

Comment: [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/hash.html)'s has support for the standard containers.

Comment: "I don't want to implement a hash function for lists!" why not? It doesn't have to be particularly complicated. See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/hash/combine.html. If you don't want a boost dependency the implementation of `hash_combine` is not long.

Comment: In the worst case, I'll have to go with a `set`. I can't think of a good hash function for a `list` of `string`.

Comment: Thanks chris and Steve :)

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19740245) might help you.

Comment: That's perfect Daniel! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyClass {
private:
    struct Hash : public std::unary_function< std::list<std::string> const& ls, 
                                                                       size_t> {
        std::size_t operator()(std::list<std::string> const& ls) const;
    };
typedef boost::unordered_set< std::list<std::string>, Hash > MyClassSet;
MyClassSet set_;
};

std::size_t MyClass::Hash::operator()(std::list<std::string> const& ls) const {
    std::size_t seed = 0;
    std::list<std::string>::iterator it = ls.begin();
    while ( it != ls.end()) {
      boost::hash_combine(seed, *it);
      ++it;
    }
    return seed;
}
```